# How to extend an abstract Syntax Analyzer Java class for a simple programming language like Ada

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I need to write a Syntax Analyser Java class. To do so, I am supposed to extend an Abstract Syntax Analyzer java class that is provided.

I know this should be quite straightforwards, but I've spent quite a healthy amount of time trying to get started and just feel... stuck.

This is the abstract class I have been provided with.

```
public abstract class AbstractSyntaxAnalyser
{

    LexicalAnalyser lex ;

    Token nextToken ;

    Generate myGenerate = null;


    public abstract void _statementPart_() throws IOException, CompilationException;


    public abstract void acceptTerminal(int symbol) throws IOException, CompilationException;



    public void parse( PrintStream ps ) throws IOException
    {
        ps.println( lex.getFilename() );
        myGenerate = new Generate();
        try {
            nextToken = lex.getNextToken() ;
            _statementPart_() ;
            acceptTerminal(Token.eofSymbol) ;
            myGenerate.reportSuccess() ;
            ps.println( "OK\n" );
        }
        catch( CompilationException ex )
        {
            ps.println( "Compilation Exception" );
            ps.println( ex.toTraceString() );
            ps.println( "STOP\n" );
        }
    }
}
```

As a new Java user, I would really appreciate help and guidance on how to get this project moving as this is merely the first step in a whole list of things to do and I just can't seem to make any headway..

All the best!

Comment: Please paste this code into the question so that we all can see it. Web links change in time, and that would make this question and (hopefully) its answers worthless to future searchers. Thank you.

Comment: I have heard Ada described many ways, but "simple" is not one of them. From the [Ada (programming language) Wikipedia Entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_(programming_language)), *Early Ada compilers struggled to implement the large, complex language, and both compile-time and run-time performance tended to be slow and tools primitive.*

Comment: Ada is anything but a simple language.

Comment: Do you mean something other than `public class SyntaxAnalyser extends AbstractSyntaxAnalyser` **?**

Comment: What I am supposed to do is write a java class syntax analyzer. My only instructions are to extend the provided class as appropriate.

I have been learning the theoretical behind all of this, but have yet to touch on how it is actually applied which is why I feel so hung-up as I'm starting to try and actually turn it into code.

Comment: I see now that Ada is evidently much more complicated than was let on in this module. What I am attempting to implement is a 'simple language'. For example:

    <statement part> ::= begin <statement list> end
    <statement list> ::= <statement> | <statement list> ; <statement>
    <statement> ::= <assignment statement> | <if statement> | <while statement> |
                              <procedure statement> | <until statement> | <for statement>
etc.

Comment: @user207421well I guess I just won an award for that. Thank you

Comment: @ArthurDecker I'm serious. You removed most of the relevant infomation, including the words 'syntax analyser' and  'Ada', and you jumped to the conclusion that his only problem was essentially with the `extends` keyword.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch To be fair, syntax of Ada (even 2012) is quite simple. It is the semantics (especially for overloading resolution, as in Ada you can overload on any number of parameters, including return parameter from function) that are quite difficult.

Answer (score 2):

To extend that class you need to provide an implementation of all the abstract methods.  A do-nothing example would be

```
public class MySyntaxAnalyzer extends AbstractSyntaxAnalyzer{

   public void _statementPart_() throws IOException, CompilationException{
   }

   public void acceptTerminal(int symbol) throws IOException, CompilationException{    
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So by doing this we're just defining each of the functions from the abstract class?

Comment: Yes. In the example above, they don't do anything. Usually the abstract class would include javadoc (or you'd be given a specification) describing what the abstract methods are supposed to do; it'd be up to you to make them actually do that.